# Analysis of the ratio $D(n)/n$ (Reference request)

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, reference-request, divisor-sum, arithmetic-functions

In his undergraduate honors thesis at Penn State University, Kurt Ludwick analyzed the ratio $\sigma(n)/n$, where $\sigma = \sigma_{1}$ is the classical sum-of-divisors function.  (His thesis was titled *Analysis of the ratio $\sigma(n)/n$*.  I would have included a hyperlink if an online copy of the same was available.  I did find the following hyperlink, but it appears to be broken: <https://www.math.temple.edu/~ludwick/thesis/thesisinfo.html>)

Here is my question:

> Have similar theses/researches/studies been done on analyzing/investigating the nature of the ratio $D(n)/n$, where $D(n)=2n-\sigma(n)$ is the [deficiency](http://oeis.org/A033879) of $n \in \mathbb{N}$?

Notice that
$$\dfrac{D(n)}{n}=\dfrac{2n-\sigma(n)}{n}=2-\dfrac{\sigma(n)}{n}.$$

Comment: There is no need of separate studies for $D(n)/n$ because of the last formula in your question. Anything found about $\sigma(n)/n$ is immediately translated to $D(n)/n$.

Comment: $\frac{\sigma(n)}{n} \leq e^\gamma$ where $\gamma$ is the Euler constant. which means that $\frac{D(n)}{n} \leq 2-e^\gamma$

Comment: @Ahmad, assuming $I(n) = \sigma(n)/n \leq e^{\gamma}$ is correct, isn't that supposed to imply
$$2 - I(n) = \frac{D(n)}{n} \geq 2 - e^{\gamma}?$$

Comment: @Ahmad, any way, I believe what is known is that the Riemann hypothesis is true if and only if Robin's inequality
$$\frac{\sigma(n)}{n} < e^{\gamma}\log\log{n}$$
is satisfied for $n \geq 5041$.

Comment: @Jose Arnaldo Bebita Dris true, i missed it. that is what i was going to write , thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the abstract of the arXiv preprint titled [Analysis of the Ratio $D(n)/n$](https://arxiv.org/abs/1703.09077):

> In this note, we investigate properties of the ratio $D(n)/n$, which we will call the deficiency index. We will discuss some concepts recast in the language of the deficiency index, based on similar considerations in terms of the abundancy index.